# Extract a route from a string using regex and python

Tags: python, regex

I can't seem to find where is the problem here.

I'm trying to extract a route from the following string.

```
s = '{2010501005|XXGpvertex|18|0|35|0|{|{30100001|XXparameter_set|@@@@{{30001002|XXparameter|!prototype_path|$AB_COMPONENTS/Partitioning/Concatenate.mpc|3|2|Pf$|@{0|}}'
```

What I´m trying to achieve here is to obtain the route **$AB_COMPONENTS/Partitioning/Concatenate.mpc** but so far I have made it to:

```
re.search('prototype_path\|(.*)\|', s, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

which gives me the output:

```
$AB_COMPONENTS/Partitioning/Concatenate.mpc|3|2|Pf$|@{0
```

I don´t seem to know why it keeps going until the last pipe, does anybody know what's going on?

It´s important to know that I can´t use the number 3 that comes after the pipe. Also important that I can use the extension .mp as a delimiter. but that also can´t figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `.*` regexp is greedy put instead

.*?

You can read more here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

What happens is that `.*` will consume as much as input as possible (in your case going all the way until the last pipe) 
`.*?` instead will consume as little as possible (in your case will stop at the first pipe)

also an alternative and faster way would be to split by what apparently looks like the field delimiter and then select the right row

```
"|".split(row)[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy regexp,

```
.*?
```

instead of a greedy one

```
.*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
re.findall('\|([^|]+?\.mpc)\|', text, re.I)
```

As others have suggested, your original pattern was too greedy. Since all you need is the text that ends in '.mpc' and all text blocks are delimited by pipes, you can grab all characters ending in '.mpc' that are not pipes to achieve your desired result.